Find all positive integers $x, y, z$ such that $2^x +1 =7^y +2^z$
Find all positive intergers x, y, z such that:
$2^x +1 =7^y +2^z$
I got $x=3n$ and $z=3k+1$ when tried modulo 7
Case 1: $y$ is odd $$2^{3k}(8^{n-k} - 2) = 7^y -1$$
We have $$v_2(7^y-1) = 1$$Then $$2^{3k}=1$$
$$\rightarrow k=0$$
$$\rightarrow (x,y,z)=(3,1,1)$$
Case 2: $y$ is even
Let $y=2p$
If $p$ is odd then we have $(x,y,z)=(6,2,4)$
And I got stuck when $p$ is even.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, using an Approach0 search, there are the AoPS threads Diophantine Equation, number theory problem from VNTST and TWO NUMBER THEORY problem (in this last one, your problem is #$2$ in the first post, and an answer is in post #$15$).
